# Javascript - On Click, Start a timer to Swap a Button/Image and also Show a Content Locker

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a complete noob with this, so sorry,

What I'm trying to do is, on my Wordpress Blog I have a button/Image: `src="http://Mysite.com/Images/Button.png"`
I would like for when a user Clicks this Image 2 things to happen - 1. For my Content Locker to pop up, I believe that i already have the correct code for that?:

```
 onclick="var fileref=document.createElement('script');fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); fileref.setAttribute('src', 'http://MYCONTENTLOCKER.com/guid?:1234567890')
```

For this content locker to trigger, The whole action needs to have a ID e.g. 'ID="button1'

And 2. For a timer to start for say 30 Seconds.

When that timer ends, i would like the original button/image to be replaced with a different button/image. And when that is clicked i would like a text string to appear below the button - saying something e.g. 'You've completed this part'

I know that this is a lot to ask, and I will be so very grateful if someone helps me out here!

Thanks!
Harry.

Comment: Can you post some code, or a link to some code, so we can see the page structure? What is contained in this "fileref" script you're attaching?

Comment: Could you explain what's a content locker?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delay with:

```
setTimeout(someFunction,30000);
```

This will run the function after 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds).

You should wrap the button in a span or something and then you can get the container element and replace the button/image like so:

```
function someFunction() {
  document.getElementById('container_name').innerHTML = '<button onclick="do something">A new button</button>';
}
```

Place an empty span below this image and do the same with that:

```
function someFunction() {
  document.getElementById('container_name').innerHTML = '<button onclick="do something">A new button</button>';
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'You have completed this part!';
}
```

I have no idea how to do the first part though.